# how to check the invalid dates in a table in DB2

Tags: db2

how to check the invalid dates for a date column in DB2.

We have few date columns in db2 while fetching the data in an etl job we are getting ":000-01-01" but when we see the data in the table it shows proper dates..

Is there any way to find out invalid dates in date column in DB2

Please let me know if this question is repeated ...

Comment: What is the exact column-datatype in Db2 for the date column, and what is the SQL used to retrieve/format such columns?

Comment: Are you certain of that?  Are the columns with Db2-datatype = DATE nullable (i.e. allow null )?  Again, what SQL is used to retrieve/format the colums?

Comment: @Arya What's the etl tool and what's the corresponding date value in the db2 column?

Comment: if the column uses a date datatype, then it can not contain an invalid date.

Comment: What platform? Db2 (LUW),  zOS, IBM i?  What version?